# Magento 2.4: UI component paging with non-collection DataProvider

Tags: frontend, uicomponent, magento2.4, pagination, data-provider

I have listed UI component with DataProvider that is not a collection. I want to make pagination for it but when I add simply toolbar and pagination nodes in XML it does not work. I can see that I have e.g. 3 pages, but everyone has the same content: all items from DataProvider.

Getting request params in DataProvider like page size does not work in Magento 2.4. Is there any other solution than creating a new entity with Model, ResourceModel, and Collection?